# Assistance needed with JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm creating a JSON file to hold information for commands.

The JSON file holds the trigger and repsonse for the commands, I have one in the file, but I want to add more, but when I do I get an error

```
{

  "trigger": "twitter",
  "repsonse": "https://www.twitter.com/Fhaelin"
}

{
  "trigger": "test",
  "repsonse": "This is a test command"
}
```

I get thrown errors and i dont know why

Here's the code I'm using to read it:

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {
  var input = message.content.toLowerCase();

  if (input === prefix + Commands.trigger)
  {
    bot.sendMessage(message, message.author + " : " + Commands.repsonse)
  }
})
```

Whole code
http://hastebin.com/punabobisu.coffee

Comment: share the console error

Comment: Where is the code? What is the error?

Comment: Heres a screenhot http://prntscr.com/blba5m

Comment: @AcidzDesigns: *Pictures* of code are not useful. Show *code*, as text in the question. (There's an "edit" link you can use.)

Comment: Please use proper capitalization and punctuation in SO questions and answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your question about how to put multiple commands in the JSON is **answered**. If you have a question about how to **read** that file, that's a separate question. I suggest asking it separately, with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You get errors because that's an invalid JSON document. There can only be **one** top-level value in a JSON document.

To have a list of objects, put them in an array: `[..., ...]`:

```
[
  {
    "trigger": "twitter",
    "response": "https://www.twitter.com/Fhaelin"
  },
  {
    "trigger": "test",
    "response": "This is a test command"
  }
]
```

---

Side note: You have a consistent misspelling in your question: It's "response", not "repsonse". Only mentioning it because it'll come back to bite you at some stage if you actually put it in your code.

Comment: *(For got the CW tickbox. If it's not a CW above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Ok, the array got rid of the error, now i dont get a response

Comment: @AcidzDesigns: You have to consume it slightly differently, but there's no code in your question, so we can't help you consume it.

Comment: Would you like the whole program?

Comment: @AcidzDesigns: See the comment on the question. And note that the content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Good luck.